# How to prove that the graphs of unbounded linear operators $A$ and $A''$ are isomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators

I'm reading Theorem 3.24 in Brezis's book of Functional Analysis.

> Let $E$ and $F$ be two reflexive Banach spaces. Let $A: D(A) \subseteq E \rightarrow$ $F$ be an unbounded linear operator that is densely defined and closed. Then $D\left(A'\right)$ is dense in $F'$. Thus $A'': D\left(A''\right) \subseteq E'' \rightarrow F''$ is well defined and it may also be viewed as an unbounded operator from $E$ into $F$. Then we have $A''=A$.

Below I can only show that there is an isometric embedding from the graph of $A$ to that of $A''$. I could **not** prove that this embedding is indeed surjective. I have **not** used the fact that $A$ is closed. The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372422/if-e-f-are-reflexive-banach-spaces-then-the-graphs-of-unbounded-linear-operat) of the author does use this fact.

Could you elaborate on how to finish my proof?

---

**My attempt:** Let $J_1, J_2$ be the canonical isometric isomorphisms from $E$ to $E''$ and from $F$ to $F''$ respectively. First, we show that $J_1 [D(A)] \subseteq D(A'')$. Let $x \in D(A)$. Then $\langle J_1 x, f \rangle = \langle f, x \rangle \le |x| \cdot \|f\|$ for all $f\in D(A')$. So $J_1 x \in D(A'')$. Next we show that $A'' (J_1x) = J_2(Ax)$ for all $x\in D(A)$. In fact, $$\langle A''(J_1x), f \rangle = \langle J_1 x, A'f \rangle = \langle A'f,x \rangle = \langle f, Ax \rangle, \quad \forall f \in D(A').$$

On the other hand, $\langle  J_2(Ax), f \rangle = \langle f, Ax \rangle$ for all $f \in F^\star$. It follows that $\langle A''(J_1x) - J_2(Ax), f \rangle = 0$ for all $f \in D(A')$. Because $D(A')$ is dense in $F'$, we get $A''(J_1x) - J_2(Ax) = 0_{F''}$ and thus $A''(J_1x) = J_2(Ax)$.

Let $G(A)$ and $G(A'')$ be the graphs of $A,A''$ respectively. Clearly, $G(A)$ is a vector subspace of $E \times F$. Also, $G(A'')$ is a vector subspace of $E'' \times F''$. Consider $$J:E \times F \to E'' \times F'', (x,y) \mapsto (J_1 x, J_2y).$$

Then $J$ is an isometric isomorphism. We have $J[G(A)] \subseteq G(A'')$.

Comment: When Brezis writes that $A^{''}$ can be viewed as an unbounded operator from $E$ to $F$, he means the operator with domain $\{x\in E\mid J_1(x)\in D(A^{''}),A^{''}(J_1(x))\in J_2(F)\}$ that maps $x$ to $J_2^{-1}(A''(J_1(x))$.

Comment: @MaoWao In your direction, we have not used the assumption $A$ is closed. On the other hand, the author proved that $G(A'') = G(A)$ (I guess he meant $G(A'') \cong G(A)$). Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii1JY.png).

Comment: @MaoWao It seems I "found" a proof that the graphs of $A$ and $A''$ isometrically isomorphic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372422/if-e-f-are-reflexive-banach-spaces-then-the-graphs-of-a-and-a-are-isome). If you don't mind, please have a check on my attempt.